# Assembly throughout two projects

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, share, .net-assembly

I want to separate the logic from the GUI in my project. I built a class library and an application, both with the same AssemblyName and Namespaces. When I reference the DLL in my application, I still can't use my internal classes. What should i exactly do?

I have tried setting the ComVisible to true but it didn't work.

Should I have all my classes as public?

Comment: Using the same name/namespaces is a bad idea so change that, otherwise you need [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn467695.aspx)

Comment: Why you used same AssemblyName and Namespaces?

Comment: It's my first time trying to do this so..?

Comment: Okay so @Sayse I should change the namespace in my DLL? and reference it? Will that make the "internal" classes accessible

Comment: You should choose different Assembly name and make the classes public which you want to use in exe project.

Comment: internal classes only used in same Assembly,So you can not use internal classes in exe project.

Comment: Well Yea, I presumed you were referencing it anyway so that is a definite, but it is just confusing and cumbersome to have the same names for both.

Comment: I just changed the namespace on the DLL project but keeping the same AssemblyName. And I can't Access my classes still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what i wanted and this is how.

Expand the properties in the solution explorer and open AssemblyInfo.cs and use this line of code.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NAME_OF_NAMESPACE")]
```

This way i was able to deal with my internal classes that were in my DLL project from the other GUI project.